# How do I get the IE enter/go key?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

How do I change the enter key on my app keyboard so it looks like this:
Is their something I have to import?

[image: Key from IE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Phone devices, this is how the keyboard looks for textboxes with the URL input scope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28VS.96%29.aspx

In your XAML you can simply set your URL scope

`<TextBox InputScope="Url">`

For examples, see:
http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/10/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-10-inputscope-textboxes/

Comment: "Search" InputScope also has this button